# Multicollinearity - continuous and dummy variables

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics, multicollinearity

I know that one of the assumptions of Gauss-Markov is no perfect multicollinearity. If I want to run a model that estimates the effect of gambling on wages, would this model be appropriate:

Wage = Number of hours spent gambling per day + A dummy that = 1 if the individual has gambled more than intended at least 3x in the past year

In this example, I basically want to see if wages are impacted by an increase in the number of hours spent gambling but on top of that, I want to see if problem gambling (which is proxied by that dummy) has an extra effect on wages.

Are there any issues from having a model like this or is it normal?

Comment: "Gambled more than intended"--is that for more money or spending more time? If the former, then the correlation need not be extremely large. The danger of high collinearity will become greater as you add more predictors to the model. I suspect that a greater concern will be outliers--a Pareto distribution on "time spent," where a few are consumed by gambling, while for many it is a marginal activity.

Answer (score 1):

Multicolinearity problem would come to bite you when your data matrix $X$ has deficient rank, i.e. $Rank(X) \leq k$. In your example, you will have a cross-section of individuals, and your data matrix would have three columns (constant, #of hours, the dummy). Unless you have everyone in your sample gambled more than 3x in the past year, I don't see why you would run into the multicolinearity problem.